# Multiple Domains on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, dns, virtualhost, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

If I have an app hosted on firebase at `domain.com`, but I also need other domains fetch data from other parts of the URL Hierarchy of `domain.com`. For example `domain.com/some_folder/` would be the Web Root to `AnotherDomain.Com`.

I would like to make this work without any server dependency, strictly using firebase cloud functions.

I understand that a manual DNS change would be required on `AnotherDomain.Com` to point to a host that would invoke this function.